# SICP Exercise 4.54

Tags: scheme, sicp

I have a question about Exercise 4.54 from Section 4.3.3 of Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs (http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-28.html#%_sec_4.3.3). This exercise concerns the Amb evaluator.

The exercise is the following:

> If we had not realized that `require` could be implemented as an ordinary procedure that uses `amb`, to be defined by the user as part of a nondeterministic program, we would have had to implement it as a special form. This would require syntax procedures
>
> `(define (require? exp) (tagged-list? exp 'require))`
>
> `(define (require-predicate exp) (cadr exp))`
>
> and a new clause in the dispatch in `analyze`
>
> `((require? exp) (analyze-require exp))`
>
> as well the procedure `analyze-require` that handles `require` expressions. Complete the following definition of `analyze-require`.
>
> ```
> (define (analyze-require exp)
>   (let ((pproc (analyze (require-predicate exp))))
>     (lambda (env succeed fail)
>       (pproc env
>              (lambda (pred-value fail2)
>                (if <??>
>                    <??>
>                    (succeed 'ok fail2)))
>              fail))))
> ```

I completed it as follows:

```
(define (analyze-require exp)
  (let ((pproc (analyze (require-predicate exp))))
    (lambda (env succeed fail)
      (pproc env
             (lambda (pred-value fail2)
               (if (false? pred-value)
                   (fail2) ;; or (fail)
                   (succeed 'ok fail2)))
             fail))))
```

My doubt is the following:

I know that, during execution, when the predicate value `pred-value` is false, `require` should fail; that is, it should call a failure continuation procedure. But I'm a bit confused as to whether it should call `(fail)` or `(fail2)`. Which one is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(fail2)` is the correct one. The procedure conforms to a [continuation-passing style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style), and the correct continuation procedure in this case is `fail2`.

Answer (score 0):

I think `(fail)` is correct.

Here we have got `pred-value`, which means `pproc` evaluates well for now. But if it is `false` value, we treat it as bad as `pproc` evaluates wrong. so the continuation here is `fail` not `fail2`.

A test can be found here:

- https://wizardbook.wordpress.com/2011/01/22/exercise-4-54/

Answer (score 0):

`(fail2)`is correct, well,most of the time it doesn't matter whichever you choose,but for the following conditons:

1.the predicate part contains (amb) such as

`(require (amb false true false true true))`

2.the predicate part contains (set! <...> <...>)

you can check it out,this is because most of the process's fail-continuation is the same as its caller's except for the above two kinds of processes. Though it sounds some kind of ridiculous.